# Scala spark - construct array of struct from columns set from a row

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to scala/spark.

My data frame:

```
# column Header #
id    A1    B1    C1    A2     B2     C2     A3      B3     C3  .................. A40 B40 C40
# data #
1   x   y   z   a    b    c    null  null  null .............................
2   a   b   c   null null null null  null  null .................. m   n   o 
3   x   y   z   null null null d     e     f ................................
```

expected output

```
1  [{id:1,A:x,B:y,C:z},{id:2,A:a,B:b,C:c}]
2  [{id:1,A:a,B:b,C:c},{id:40,A:m,B:n,C:o}]
3  [{id:1,A:x,B:y,C:z},{id:3,A:d,B:e,C:f}]
```

Comment: Next time please format your data better, and add an actual explanation of your problem and what you have done so far

Answer (score 1):

Check below code.

```
scala> df.show(false)
+---+---+---+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|id |A1 |B1 |C1 |A2  |B2  |C2  |A3  |B3  |C3  |
+---+---+---+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|1  |x  |y  |z  |a   |b   |c   |null|null|null|
|2  |a  |b  |c  |null|null|null|m   |n   |o   |
|3  |x  |y  |z  |null|null|null|d   |e   |f   |
+---+---+---+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

```
val colExpr = to_json(
    filter(
        array(
            df
            .columns
            .tail
            .map(_.split(""))
            .groupBy(d => d.last)
            .flatMap(d => Seq(Seq(lit(d._1).as("id")) ++  d._2.map(_.head).map(c => col(s"${c}${d._1}").as(c))))
            .map(hd => when(hd.tail.map(c => c.isNotNull).reduce(_ and _),struct(hd:_*)))
            .toSeq:_*
        ).as("data"),
        column => column.isNotNull
    )
).as("data")
```

**Final Output**

```
scala> df.select($"id",colExpr).show(false)
+---+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|id |data                                                                   |
+---+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1  |[{"id":"2","A":"a","B":"b","C":"c"},{"id":"1","A":"x","B":"y","C":"z"}]|
|2  |[{"id":"1","A":"a","B":"b","C":"c"},{"id":"3","A":"m","B":"n","C":"o"}]|
|3  |[{"id":"1","A":"x","B":"y","C":"z"},{"id":"3","A":"d","B":"e","C":"f"}]|
+---+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**Note**: Spark Version `3.0`

Comment: Thank you for your quick help Srinivas. I am using spark 2.4 and let me try to see if I can implement in my environment. Thanks

Comment: Yes, I think it will work in spark 2.4 .. see if it has hof filter function.